# VBA extract numerator and denominator with named values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to extract the numerator and denominator of a range of cells using VBA.

So for example, in cell A1 the formula is: =NV2/NV3. NV2 and NV3 are named values and are for example NV2 = 3 and NV3=6. In text, the result of the formula in A1 would be 0.5.

What would be the approach to retrieve NV2 and NV3? I need to somehow make reference to the formula I believe.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Range("A1").Formula will return the formula as a string.  You could then parse out the Names.

Answer (score 2):

Select the cells you wish to examine and run:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Formula
        If r.HasFormula And InStr(v, "/") > 0 Then
            ary = Split(Mid(v, 2), "/")
            msg = r.Address & vbCrLf & v & vbCrLf & ary(0) & vbCrLf & ary(1)
            MsgBox msg
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 nicely done and `Range(ary(0)).Value` or `Range(ary(1)).Value` would give the named cell value if needed.

Comment: Thanks ZAT, however in my case it is a bit more complicated. I hav e for numerator for example x values: NV1 + NV2 + NV3 and for denominator the same: NV4 + NV5 + NV6. How can these be easily converted to the correct numeric values?